# onmouseover and onmouseout functions containing intervals not executing correctly

Tags: javascript, intervals, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am doing some experimentation with JavaScript and I have a list of 4 items displayed horizontally, with each list item having an `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` event assigned.

The `onmouseover` event for each item executes a function which increases the height of the item over time using an interval.

the `outmouseover` event for each item executes a function which then reduces the height of the item to its default value over time using another interval.

It is working in the following scenario:
When I trigger the `onmouseover` for a list item the height increases as expected, and when I take the mouse off the list item the height then decreases as expected.

The problem is however, it doesn't seem to work in the following scenario:
When I trigger the `onmouseover` for a list item the height increases as expected, however if I trigger another `onmouseover` event for another list item *before* the item has returned to its original size, the `onmouseout` function for the previous list item does not finish executing.

Sorry if I am lacking any detail, evidently I am incredibly bad at explaining things.... So I have a link to the source code and a site where you can test the code to see what is happening.

Maybe I do not have as much of a knowledge of javascript as I thought, so while a solution or fix would be amazing, I am also happy to accept any advice or some kind of explanation as to why this could be happening.

I thought initially that multiple interval timers could not execute simultaneously, until after some research I found they can. So now I am thinking if it is a conflict between the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events.

Any advice, guidance or a solution would be extremely appreciated!

Source:
https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B6XLOOGyKVdWVkpSUklmMVI5QUk 
Testing Site:
http://www.play-hookey.com/htmltest/
(just copy the contents of that google document and paste into the html text area in the site to see what I am talking about)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code:

```
icon.onmouseover = function(){ enlarge(this, icon.ID); };
icon.onmouseout = function(){ reduce(this, icon.ID); };
```

Correct code:

```
icon.onmouseover = function(){ enlarge(this, this.ID); };
icon.onmouseout = function(){ reduce(this, this.ID); };
```

What happened:  you bindded an event with a function and passed variables to it. After each for loop, you redefined that function variable (so at the end, your icon.ID=3). That means that all on event called functions where using same icon.ID=3.

I hope that make sense...

Comment: Wow thanks! Kind of hating myself that I missed that... Working perfectly now!